# Quick-start sample app for PHP

Tags: php, login, oauth2, google-api

Estou fazendo um website e quero implementar o login pelo Google usando Quick -start sample app for PHP.

No entanto quando vou rodar a página `signin.php` aparece a opção de fazer o login pelo Google +, mas ao fazer o login eu permaneço na mesma página e nada acontece.

Teoricamente, segundo a documentação do Google, a página deveria chamar uma função javaScript e mostrar meus dados.

[print da tela após logar com a conta do Google +](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7RoU.png)

Referências: https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php?hl=pt-br#step_2_set_up_the_languagecapfirst_quick-start_app